# Copy recipient names from Outlook Meeting item

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an open Outlook meeting item.

I would enter the name of the recipients manually and run a macro which would copy the recipients to the clipboard.

Here is a screenshot where there are two recipients. The macro should copy two names into the clipboard.
[image]

My code copies the entire code not the recipient names.

```
Sub cellSel()

    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim objWSS

    Set objWSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objWSS.SendKeys "^a"
    objWSS.SendKeys "^c"
    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipboard.GetFromClipboard

    If TypeName(ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
        If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            MsgBox (clipboard.GetText)
            With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.ActiveDocument
                With .Tables(1)
                    '.Cell(2, 2).Range.Select
                    .Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = clipboard.GetText
                    '.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = clipboard.GetText
                End With
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.AppointmentItem.Recipients) property to get the recipient names. The property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item.

Use `Recipients (index)`, where `index` is the name or index number, to return a single Recipient object. The name can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

```
Sub DemoMeetingRecipients() 
 Dim myAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
 Dim myPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 Dim d As Long 
 Dim myInt As Long 

 Set myAppointment = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 

 For d = 1 To myAppointment.Recipients.count 
 Debug.Print myAppointment.Recipients.item(d).name 
 Debug.Print myAppointment.Recipients.item(d).Type 
 Set myPA = myAppointment.Recipients.item(d).PropertyAccessor 
 myInt = myPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39050003") 
 Debug.Print myInt 
 Debug.Print "---" 
 Next d 
End Sub
```